# How to retrieve closest value to mean and its location C

Tags: c

I was just wondering how you would get the closest value to the mean, the program retrieves input from the user and then outputs a 2D array, within the two ranges the user inputted. It then also outputs lowest and highest array values, the mean(all of this has been coded), I'm just unsure how to write a function to return the closest value in the array to the mean and then the location within the array.

Comment: It would be good to see any attempts you have made.

Comment: Also, `fflush(stdin)` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have added as much as possible to the original post @AjayBrahmakshatriya but don't know where to go from there

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Subtract the mean value from each element.
2. Take the absolute value of the result.
3. Store the position and element which have lowest difference.

   ```
    int fnFindClosestVal(int arn2DArray[][6], int nRows, int nCols, double nTotal, int *posRow, int *posCol)
       {
           int nClosestValue = arn2DArray[0][0];
           int nDiff = abs(arn2DArray[0][0] - nTotal);
           int Row,Col;

           for (nCountRows = 0; nCountRows < nRows; nCountRows++)
           {
               for (nCountCols = 0; nCountCols < nCols; nCountCols++)
               {
                       if(abs(arn2DArray[nCountRows][nCountCols] - nTotal) < nDiff)
                        {
                           nDiff = abs(arn2DArray[nCountRows][nCountCols] - nTotal);
                           nClosestValue = arn2DArray[nCountRows][nCountCols];
                           *posRow = nCountRows;
                           *posCol = nCountCols;
                        }
               }
           }
       return nClosestValue;
   }
   ```

Comment: this is great thanks! how would I go about outputting the location of the closest value? @Shihab

Comment: in the main method I've got printf("\nThe closest value to the mean is %6d and the location is \n", fnFindClosestVal(arn2DArray, 5, 6, fnFindAverageValue(arn2DArray, 5, 6))); is there any way of inserting this location within the printf statement

Comment: So you need to return multiple values from the function. In that case you have to pass those variables as pointers to the function.

Comment: I'm not really too sure about how this would be done. Sorry I'm quite new to C. @Shihab

Comment: Function modified accordingly. call the function as below.  int posRow; int posCol; fnFindClosestVal(arn2DArray, nRows, nCols, nTotal, &posRow, &posCol);  print(posRow and posCol);